# R package checking

Tags: r, package, cran

I just recently submitted an update of my package to CRAN,  and I was notified that a line in an .Rd file was too wide. Using the latest Rpatched version,  I ran the R CMD check,  everything checked out ok.  I ran the  --as-cran on the tarball and everything is ok.  When I examined the .PDF file created after R CMD build, I do see that the line in the .PDF help file extended beyond page margin.

My question is where and how do I check for errors in the creation of the .PDF file?  I've checked through Writing R Extensions, etc. and I can't find a specific statement.

Answer (score 3):

Build and check your package R CMD build mypkg && R CMD check mypkg_1.2.3.tar.gz. Then look in mypkg.Rcheck/Rdlatex.log for warnings (like Overful \hbox) while processing the Rd file to latex.

Comment: Or use `devtools::check()`. To guarantee you're checking against the latest daily, use `devtools::build_win()`